# Series of a partial sums limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $$a_n=\frac{n^3+n+1}{3n^2-1}$$
How to show that series of the partial sums of this series has a limit?

Comment: Unless you allow $\infty$ as a limit, it doesn't, it blows up.

Answer (score 1):

It is not true (unless you mean that the limit is $+\infty$). For any $n\geq 1,$
$$a_n=\frac{n^3+n+1}{3n^2-1}\geq \frac{n^3-\frac{1}{3}n}{3n^2-1}=\frac{n}{3}$$
so:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n \geq \frac{N^2}{6}.$$

Comment: @AndréNicolas: thanks, now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, we would say this series does not have a limit. One standard theorem is that if $\lim a_n \neq 0$, then $\sum a_n$ diverges. Since your sequence doesn't converge at all, you can conclude the series does not either.

Answer (score 0):

this term has the limit $+\infty$ since $a_n=n\cdot \frac{1+\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n^3}}{3-\frac{1}{n^2}}$